# org.json.JSONException: Value success<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject android

Tags: android

Here, I am trying to get response from PHP server. My Response in logcat is like this

05-11 08:04:43.760: E/IMAGE_RESPONSE(10577): success

05-11 08:04:43.760: E/IMAGE_RESPONSE(10577): **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/swapclon/rails2.swapclone.com/eventdemo/upload.php:14) in **/home/swapclon/rails2.swapclone.com/eventdemo/upload.php** on line **20**

05-11 08:04:43.760: E/IMAGE_RESPONSE(10577): {"msg":"Sucess!!","name":"logo_49152_forest.jpeg","name_old":"forest.jpeg"}

And my Android coding for getting response is like this..

```
   String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
           Log.e("IMAGE_RESPONSE",response1);
           dialog.dismiss();


           if(response1.contains("name"))
           {
               Log.e("ifff","iff");
               jsobje = parseJSON(response1); 
               if(jsobje != null) 
               {
                  String iii= jsobje.getString("name");
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here my first response get converted into JSON. But I only want to convert
```

The problem is your first response is not a valid `JSON`. I would prefer to add the JSON parsing inside method

```
public JSONObject parseJSON(String response){

    try {
        return new JSONObject(response);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, You will know if the response is a `Valid JSON`. So change you logic to call this method to parse the `JSON String` to `JSONObject` and then access the `JSON attributes` if not null

```
 String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 Log.e("IMAGE_RESPONSE",response1);
 dialog.dismiss();
 jsobje = parseJSON(response1);
 if(jsonobje != null) {
    String iii= jsobje.getString("name");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Ya, my first response is not JSON. But my last response is valid json. I dont need to access my first and second response. I want to access only my third response. And I have tried as you suggested, but it is giving same exception that  05-11 08:51:33.020: W/System.err(16101): org.json.JSONException: Value success<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject. Is there any way to access only third response directily???

Comment: Add a check if(response1.contains("name")){  jsobje = parseJSON(response1);         
        }

Comment: still it is giving same exception.. 05-11 09:05:45.660: W/System.err(19151): org.json.JSONException: Value success<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject It is going in if condition but doesn't allow to convert in JSON...

Comment: Here, I want to access only value of name from response. Is there any way to access only name directly???

Comment: No. You need to check if the string contains name and parse only that response. Post the updated code

Comment: can you try debugging what was the response string when the if condition satisfy

Comment: Sorry.. but I cant get you. What to write for printing response when if condition satisfy??

Comment: Logically want I suggested should work, if condition will satisfy only if the response string has name. I would suggest you to debug and see what goes wrong, since I don't have your complete code.

Comment: Ya it is going in if condition.. but it did not allow me to convert that string to json. it is giving same exception.